# User-friendly javascript tool for picking coordinates on an image

Tags: user-input, javascript

I am working on an application for managing computer-rooms.
The room-manager will see a map of the room (with tables and chairs) and can click on the image to mark the locations of computers.

The coordinates will be used to show a map of the room to users, and show on the map which computers are free to be used.

Getting the coordinates using javascript is easy (the answer to that question can be found [elsewhere on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818003/how-to-get-image-coordinates-in-javascript-when-mouse-click-the-image)).

I am hoping for an interactive tool/library, with things like:

- drag and drop
- showing coordinates while dragging the mouse
- zoom functionality
- adding/removing coordinate pairs from the image and that sort of things.

Does anybody know of such a tool?

Comment: This isn't the script shopping channel.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, didn't realise that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this page http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/, click on *View source*, get inspired and write your own jquery-ui plugin.

Comment: Thank you.I'll use this for inspiration and take some time to write my own code.